# Prove that the ratio $la+mc+ne : lb+md+nf$ will be equal to each of the ratios $a:b, c:d, e:f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that the ratio $la+mc+ne : lb+md+nf$ will be equal to each of the ratios $a:b, c:d, e:f$, if these be all equal; and that it will be intermediate in value between the greatest and least of these ratios if they be not all equal.

If all the ratios are equal: $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{e}{f}=k$

Then $a=bk, c=dk, e=fk$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{la+mc+ne}{lb+md+nf}=\dfrac{lbk+mdk+nfk}{lb+md+nf}=\dfrac{k(lb+md+nf)}{lb+md+nf}=k$

If all the ratios are not equal, prove that $la+mc+ne : lb+md+nf$ will be intermediate in value between the greatest and least of these ratios.

I don't know how to do this. I tried
$\dfrac{a}{b}=x,\ \ \dfrac{c}{d}=y,\ \ \dfrac{e}{f}=z$,  (Since the ratios are not equal)

Then $\dfrac{lbx+mdy+nfz}{lb+md+nf}$. But this looks wrong because I can't do anything with it. I also have no idea how to determine which is greatest and least among $\dfrac{a}{b},\ \ \dfrac{c}{d},\ \ \dfrac{e}{f}$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are there sign hypothesis on $a,b,\dots,m,n?$ If the three numbers $lb,md,nf$ are $>0,$ assuming wlog $x\le y\le z,$ you easily get$$x\le\dfrac{lbx+mdy+nfz}{lb+md+nf}\le z.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. My question is how can you write $lbx+mdx+nfx$ or $lbz+mdz+nfz$? Because the original statement is $la+mc+ne$, and knowing the ratios are not equal to each other then shouldn't the only acceptable statement be $la+mc+ne=lbx+mdy+nfz$? Because to me $lbx+mdx+nfx$ or $lbz+mdz+nfz$ means the ratios are all equal to $x$ or $z$. Sorry if this question sounds amateurish but this is what I'm thinking. Thanks.

Comment: In your $\dfrac{lbx+mdy+nfz}{lb+md+nf}$, I took an *upper (resp. lower) bound* (not $=$) of the numerator by replacing $x,y$ with $z$ (resp. $y,z$ with $x$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last expression isn't wrong, it's on the contrary.

$\dfrac{lb\min(x,y,z)+md\min(x,y,z)+nf\min(x,y,z)}{lb+md+nf} = \min(x,y,z) \le \dfrac{lbx+mdy+nfz}{lb+md+nf} \le \dfrac{lb\max(x,y,z)+md\max(x,y,z)+nf\max(x,y,z)}{lb+md+nf} = \max(x,y,z)$

As @Anne Bauval pointed out, I also assumed all variables to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the three numbers $lb,md,nf$ are $>0$ (else, you will easily find a counterexample).

You do not need to "determine which is greatest and least among $\dfrac{a}{b},\ \ \dfrac{c}{d},\ \ \dfrac{e}{f}$": as previously commented, you can assume without lost of generality that$$x\le y\le z$$(by some permutation on the three $4$-tuples $(a,b,x,l),(c,d,y,m),(e,f,z,n)$). This has the advantage of simplifying the notations, avoiding the use of expressions involving $\min$ or $\max.$

Then, you easily get$$x\le\dfrac{lbx+mdy+nfz}{lb+md+nf}\le z.$$
For this, just notice that the numerator is $\ge lbx+mdx+nfx$ and $\le lbz+mdz+nfz.$

Comment: In my answer I avoided the "determine which is greatest and least", while you chose the "assuming wlog" route, however I guess the OP doesn't know why we can assume that, otherwise they wouldn't want to determine, so that could be added to the answer.